# Upload file via REST API, IPBoard

Tags: php, rest, curl, invision-power-board

Im  trying to upload files via IPBoards REST Api but dont really know how to format the files.

This is how it looks right now but only gets error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "1L296\/B",
    "errorMessage": "NO_FILES"
}
```

Code:

```
        $post = array(
         'category' => 1,
         'author' => 1,
         'title' => 'Test title',
         'description' => 'test description',
         'files' => "{'test.txt':'".file_get_contents('/home/test/test.txt')."'}",
        );
        $target_url = 'https://example.com/api/downloads/files';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$apikey.":");
        $result = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
```

Here is the api documentation: [API doc](https://invisionpower.com/developers/rest-api?endpoint=downloads%2Ffiles%2FPOSTindex)

Comment: Try: `'files' => json_encode(['test.txt' => json_encode(file_get_contents('/home/test/test.txt'))]),` instead of building the json string manually. `json_encode()` will handle any potential escaping issues.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Same error

Answer (score 1):

Try using the http_build_query method and change the $post array slightly:

> 'files' => array($filename => $contents),

And change to:

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));